# Find the generalized sum of $1+2(2)+3(2)^2+4(2^3)+...+n(2^{n-1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the generalized sum of $1+2(2)+3(2)^2+4(2^3)+...+n(2^{n-1})$

I rewrote the above sequence into: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(2^{k-1})$. The sequence looks like a hybrid of the summation $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$ and the geometric series $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^{k-1}$. However, I'm blocked. I don't know how to precede in finding the generalized formula, if there is a simple one.

Comment: This is a typical arithmetic- geometric series, let S denote this expression, find 2S and then subtract both expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to solve this by first generalizing:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1} = \frac d{dx} \sum_{k=1}^n x^k\\
= \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)\\
= \frac{-(n+1)x^n(1-x) + (1-x^{n+1})}{(1-x)^2}
$$

Now, plugging in $x=2$ gives:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1}=(n+1)2^n + (1 - 2^{n+1}). \\
= (n+1)2^n - 2\cdot2^n + 1\\
= (n-1)2^n + 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $S=2^i+2^{i+1}+\cdots+2^{n-1}$, then $2S=2^{i+1}+2^{i+2}+\cdots+2^n$ so subtracting gives $S=2^n-2^i$.

Then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}k2^{k-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}2^j=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(2^n-2^i)=n2^n-(2^n-1)=(n-1)2^n+1$